# Please explain the $*$-operator in $x^*[n]$

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I have to calculate the $IDFT$ for a signal $y_2[n]$:

\begin{align*}
y_2[n] = DFT^{-1} \Big\{ \Im m \{ \tilde{X}[k] \} \Big\}
\end{align*}

and I am allowed to use some formulas from a collection like:

\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{2}(x[n] - x^*[(-n) \text{mod} N]) = DFT^{-1} \Big\{ j\Im m\{ X[k]\} \Big\}
\end{align*}

What does this $*$-operator mean and what's it doing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $*$ means complex conjugation here. If $x[n]$ is real-valued you of course have $x[n]=x^*[n]$. The formula you quoted (wrongly, see below) comes from the fact that

$$\Im\{X[k]\}=\frac{1}{2j}\left(X[k]-X^*[k]\right)\tag{1}$$

and

$$DFT^{-1}\{X^*[k]\}=x^*[-n]\tag{2}$$

(I'm leaving out the modulo-$n$ operation here; it's always understood implicitly). Combining (1) and (2) gives

$$DFT^{-1}\{\Im\{X[k]\}\}=\frac{1}{2j}\left(x[n]-x^*[-n]\right)\tag{3}$$

If you compare (3) to the formula in your question, you'll note that there are a few typos in your formula.

Comment: Thank you! I got a CS background and we never really had anything to do with complex numbers unfortunately .. I think I have corrected my typos in my question but just to be sure; Is this identity correct:

\begin{align*}
DFT \Big\{ \frac{1}{2}(x[n] - x^*[(-n) \text{mod} N]) \Big\} = DFT^{-1} \Big\{ j \cdot \Im m\{ X[k]\} \Big\}
\end{align*}

If I got it right one should be able to transform one to the other by the inverse operation of $DFT$.

Comment: @StefanFalk: It will be correct if you remove the $DFT^{-1}$ on the right-hand side (or the $DFT$ on the left-hand side).

Comment: I should look a little closer at this. Thanks for helping me :)